# Built-in laptop screen is laggy even when external monitor is not a problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, external-monitor

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a ROG Flow Z13 (2022). I have a samsung screen (LS34A650UXLXZX ) connected with USB-C. Both have been working ok, but recently I noticed that in the built-in screen the mouse, the keyboard even dragging a window to that display is very laggy. Meanwhile in the external screen there is not such a problem. I have installed nvidia-driver-470-server

I tried to upgrade to nvidia-driver-525, nvidia-driver-515, including the server versions but after reboot the second screen is not recognized and the built-in screen remains laggy. Even is to hard to go back because the slowly mouse and response.

Also, I tried to use noveau but the problem persist.

If I unplugged the external monitor, the built-in screen still laggy. I have tried to change resolution also the refresh rate and the problem doesn't fix it.

I also disabled the secure boot option but nothing.

```
$uname -a
Linux  5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:680-67f irq:193 memory:85000000-85ffffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6800000000-6801ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:86000000-8607ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1200
       resources: iomemory:680-67f iomemory:400-3ff irq:194 memory:682e000000-682effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000025A2sv00001043sd00001A2Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

```
$ sudo dmesg|grep nvi
[    1.977340]   with environment:
[    7.818392] audit: type=1400 audit(1676831502.472:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=654 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.818402] audit: type=1400 audit(1676831502.472:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=654 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.336182] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    8.336229] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    8.630898] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 507
[    8.639022] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    8.639341] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    8.723588] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:05:15 UTC 2022
[    8.764741] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[   10.051650] Modules linked in: intel_tcc_cooling cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp af_alg coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl bnep nvidia_drm(PO+) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus mei_pxp mei_hdcp snd_soc_core nvidia(PO) snd_compress pmt_telemetry ac97_bus iwlmvm snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_hdmi pmt_class intel_rapl_msr mac80211 i915(+) binfmt_misc libarc4 snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio snd_intel_dspcfg hid_sensor_accel_3d snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_usbmidi_lib iwlwifi hid_sensor_trigger uvcvideo snd_hda_codec drm_buddy btusb snd_seq_midi videobuf2_vmalloc industrialio_triggered_buffer videobuf2_memops btrtl ttm snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core
[   10.330421] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   10.674227] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[   10.698705] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 505.
[   36.692273] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.692438] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.692528] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.722815] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.722937] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.723019] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.773912] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.774050] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   36.774142] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

Update Mar 15

I tried this and nothing fix it: a) Switch xorg to wayland. b) Different desktop (XFCE) c) Use lightdm, c)Switch between nvidia-performance and nvidia-ondemand in nvidia-settings, d)run ubuntu with previous kernel, e)different frequency 120Hz to 60Hz, f)different scaling, g)Check if Meltdown patch has been applied. The courious thing is even using without external monitor the problem persist. I thought was hardware issue and I used Windows an worked normally. Any ideas?

Update Mar 15

Sorry, also I have searched a lot and it seems nobody reports such a thing.

Update Mar 20

I ran ubuntu from liveusb with different versions. With Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.10 laggy mouse and laggy windows resizing. With Ubuntu 20.04 works perfectly. With Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't even show the GUI, black screen. Any idea?

Update Apr 15

I installed kernel 5.17 and the performance was a little better but still laggy. The external monitor didn't work at all but It seems a driver version loaded probably; I didn't tried fix it.

Also I tried to change PowerMize to Prefer Maximum performance but didn't work.

Update Jun 4

I follow this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/FlowZ13/comments/121arkr/how_to_fix_linux_on_the_2022_rog_flow_z13/
and this:
[Trying to set enable_psr=0 in /etc/default/grub, keeps being changed to i915.enable_psr=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457546/trying-to-set-enable-psr-0-in-etc-default-grub-keeps-being-changed-to-i915-ena)

In /etc/defualt/grub add:
"i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0"
in this line:
"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash""
This must be:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0"

Then
update-grub

reboot

Comment: None of these are comments. Please edit the question and add this additional info there. Comments are where we ask you questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been following this issue on Reddit and think that you may have a similar problem.  See
https://www.reddit.com/r/FlowZ13/comments/121arkr/how_to_fix_linux_on_the_2022_rog_flow_z13/

It suggests that the problem may come from the `Panel self refresh` *feature* in the Intel/Nvidia combination.  This *feature* is designed to save battery energy when nothing is happening on the screen by slowing down the screen refresh rate.

Unfortunately, the Z13 triggering a bug that makes it always slow down for the monitors driven by the Nvidia.

Fortunately, there 2 boot time variables that can be set to disable the 'feature'
and this: Trying to set enable_psr=0 in /etc/default/grub, keeps being changed to i915.enable_psr=1

In /etc/default/grub
toward the top of the file there is a line that looks like

```shell
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

you are going to want to add
`i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0` to the end of this line so that it is something like

```shell
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=i 915.enable_psr=0"
```

run: `% sudo update-grub` watching the output to make sure that there are no errors.  It there are, fix the errors, so that the finial time you run `sudo grub-update` it runs clean.

When you are ready -- `% sudo reboot`

Comment: Welcome to SE @vml!  The link on reddit really helps, especially the update that explains that that the "panel update" feature (slow screen refresh when inactive) has a bug.  I put some suggested edits into your answer that may add clarity.  You can revert them after the get reviewed if you wish.  Good research!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It was caused by a kernel update that happened in the background. If I dropped back to an older kernel (5.15), then the built in display would work and the external display would not.

The latest kernel seems to have fixed it. Try upgrading your ubuntu system. I'm currently on 5.19.0-38-generic and my built-in display is working again.

Comment: Thank you Motred. But it didn't work for me. I updated to 5.19.0-38 and nothing.