# Trying to set enable_psr=0 in /etc/default/grub, keeps being changed to i915.enable_psr=1

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, intel-graphics

I am running Kubuntu 22.04 on a tuxedo book with an Intel graphics chip, and I'm experiencing a known psr bug that causes external screens to flicker.

My coworker (who is running Linux Mint instead of Kubuntu) has successfully fixed the problem on the same model of notebook, by doing the following steps which are recommended when experiencing the bug:

1. edit /etc/default/grub and change the line
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=1"`
   to
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0"`
2. run update-grub
3. reboot

When I do this, the problem is not fixed, and upon inspection, /etc/default/grub has been changed from
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0"`
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1   i915.enable_psr=1"`

Some process keeps changing my default grub config to enable_psr=1. How can I change this?