# Ubuntu responses too slow in asus flow z13 (22.10 and 22.04 LTS)

Tags: performance

I tried both version 22.10 and 22.04 LTS on Asus Flow z13 (having i9-12900h, 16 gb ram, gpu rtx 3050 Ti, and 1Tb ssd) even from installation, it responses too slow. As i plug usb for installation, after entering installation menu, everything become slow. I tried reinstallation, every driver package for display and other possible driver. But nothing enhance the performance and it is getting worst. Movement of cursor and response of keyboard and touch everything is slow.
Any solution and something i am missing or something needs special step for installing in Asus flow z13 (tab).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)

Comment: Probably is the same problem
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455702/built-in-laptop-screen-is-laggy-even-when-external-monitor-is-not-a-problem